# How to containerize a single node app from a mono-repo that utilizes npm workspaces

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, sh

I have a mono-repo with 4 node packages:

```
/
└── apps
    ├── app1 ( "dependencies": { "lib1": "../../libs/lib1" } )
    └── app2 ( "dependencies": { "lib2": "../../libs/lib2", "express": "^4.18.2" } )
└── libs
    └── lib1  ( "dependencies": { "lib2": "../lib2", "puppeteer": "^21.1.1" } )
    └── lib2  ( "dependencies": { "node-gyp": "^9.4.0" } )
└── node_modules
└── package.json ( { ... "workspaces": ["apps/app*", "libs/lib*"], ... } )
```

As you can see:

- `app1` doesn't need `express`
- `app2` doesn't need `lib1` and `puppeteer`

I want to create Docker images for `app1` and `app2`, but I don't want to include any node_modules that the image doesn't actually need and I also don't want to include any other directories or files that the image wouldn't need.

Essentially I have two problems:

- For each app the Docker image should only include the node_modules that the app actually requires.
- Some dependencies are just symlinks to another module within the same project. So those symlinks must either be resolved recursively and directly included into the node_modules directory or the directories need to copied into the Docker image as well... but only the ones that are actually required.

At the moment, I'm just copying the entire mono-repo into the image:

```
FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18
RUN apk update && apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python3
ADD . /mono-repo
WORKDIR /mono-repo/apps/app2
```

Can I maybe list all dependencies like this?

```
npm ls -p -w ./apps/app2 | sed 1d
```

... and then somehow magically delete everything else?

---

Not sure if relevant, but I'm using GitLab CI and I have a job that installs the node_modules, puts them in the cache and then I have a docker-build job, that retrieves the node_modules from the cache to save time. So, if possible I'd like to keep using that cache in order to save time. Every CI job uses a Docker image based on alpine and the images I'm building are based on alpine as well.

Edit:
I'm using proper caching now in GitLab (The cache is stored ./.npm). So I can solve one of the problems by specifically only installing the node_modules for one workspace:

```
npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline -w "$NODE_APP_DIR"
```

I also updated the Dockerfile to run in two steps (first as builder to install dependencies and remove unnecessary files), then I just copy everything that's left into the final image:

```
# Stage 1: Create an intermediate image for npm install
FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18 as builder

# Install build dependencies
RUN apk update && apk --no-cache add build-base python3

# Copy the application code into the builder image
COPY . /mono-repo

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /mono-repo

# Set the NODE_APP_DIR ARG
ARG NODE_APP_DIR

# Run npm install in the workspace
RUN npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline -w "$NODE_APP_DIR"

# Remove everything that the app doesn't need
RUN export EXCLUDE_PATHS="$(npm ls -p -w "$NODE_APP_DIR" | sed 1d)" && echo "DEPENDENCIES: $EXCLUDE_PATHS" && find "$PWD" -name "*" | grep -vE "$(echo -en "$EXCLUDE_PATHS" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g' | sed 's/^/^/' | tr '\n' '|')"

# Stage 2: Create the final production image
FROM node:20.5.1-alpine3.18

# Copy everything that's left from the builder image
COPY --from=builder /mono-repo /mono-repo

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /mono-repo

# Set the NODE_APP_DIR ARG
ARG NODE_APP_DIR

# CMD for the final image
CMD npm start --workspace "$NODE_APP_DIR"
```

`docker build --build-args NODE_APP_DIR="apps/app2" -t app2:test`

Unfortunately this doesn't quite work. Specifically the part where I try to remove everything the app doesn't need:

```
RUN export EXCLUDE_PATHS="$(npm ls -p -w "$NODE_APP_DIR" | sed 1d)" && echo "DEPENDENCIES: $EXCLUDE_PATHS" && find "$PWD" -name "*" | grep -vE "$(echo -en "$EXCLUDE_PATHS" | sed 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g' | sed 's/^/^/' | tr '\n' '|')"
```

First I use `npm ls -p -w "$NODE_APP_DIR"` to get a list of file paths of all dependencies (recursively) that the app has. Then I use `find` to find every file in the mono-repo recursively. Then I use grep to filter out all paths that start with one of the paths that the npm ls command returned. To make this work properly, I had to sanitize the dependency list first using sed so I can use it with regex. Then I add a caret to the beginning of every line (regex), then I replace all newlines with pipes (regex) to that grep matches against any of the dependencies.

But it seems that my idea is not working. It still seems to return lots of node_modules, even though I specifically only installed the node modules for one app. Is there no better way? This whole approach feels soo hacky...